# Can I have template tag inside template tag in Django?

Tags: django

So first, of all, I have data that looks like this: 
`[{'1' : 'book'}, {'2' : 'play'}, {'3' : 'drink'}, ...]`. 
And I tried to parse 'book', 'play', and 'drink' with each key in Django template. Let me show you my code. 
views.py

```
def mainPage(request):
    categoryList = [{'1' : 'book'}, {'2' : 'play'}, {'3' : 'drink'}, ...] 
    categoryLength = len(categoryList)
    ...
    context = {
        'categoryList' : categoryList,
        'range' : range(1, categoryLength+1)
}
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

main.html

```
...
{% for int in range %}
<button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-{{int}}">{{categoryList.int}}</button>
{% endfor %}
...
```

But as you can imagine, I get error in the `{{categoryList.int}}` part. As mentioned, I'm trying to parse book, play, and drink in order. How do I do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate range variable . Simply do this :

```
{% for category in categoryList %}
  {% for cid, cname in category.items %}
     Category ID : {{cid}} Category Name : {{cname}} <br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So your final code should look like this :

```
{% for category in categoryList %}
  {% for cid, cname in category.items %}
    <button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-{{cid}}">{{cname}}</button>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. But where did ```category.items``` come from?

Comment: categoryList  is a list containg dicts ..so basically i used a items() method for each dict in categoryList

Comment: Oh, so items() is a method? Thanks. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Well I've tried, and nothing appears on the page.... What do you think is wrong? I don't get any error messages, but nothing related to the data shows up on the screen :(

Comment: Well I've changed the HTML part within, to the form I needed. ```<button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-{{cid}}">{{cname}}</button>```. All the other parts are the same.

Comment: Updated the post ...if still doesn't work ! please share the snippet you are using ..also what's the type(categoryList)

Comment: I just noticed that I parsed wrong data... Now it works perfect. Thank you very much :)